# Why can't I create a foreign key on this column?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm attempting to create two tables with a one-to-many relationship.  Here are the schemas for both of them:

```
CREATE TABLE property_key (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    property VARCHAR(4000)
);

CREATE TABLE property_value (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    prop_key VARCHAR(4000),
    prop_value VARCHAR(4000),
    lang VARCHAR(2),
    INDEX ix_land(lang)
);
```

When I attempt to add a foreign key relationship between `property_value` and `property_key` on `prop_key`, I get a weird error:

> ```
> [ALTER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1005, SQL State: HY000] 
> Can't create table 'test.#sql-a8_6' (errno: 150)
> ```

The ALTER syntax I'm using is:

```
ALTER TABLE property_value ADD CONSTRAINT fk_prop_key FOREIGN KEY (prop_key) REFERENCES property_key(property);
```

I've consulted the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on the matter, but I've satisfied all of the requirements there.  How do I mitigate this issue?

Comment: A 4000 character primary key?  Yikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that the fields are too large.  [InnoDB has a field limit of 768 bytes per key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html), and the foreign key that is being created is around 8KB.  Further, it wouldn't be possible to ensure that the foreign key is unique.

Two options to mitigate this - you can either reduce the size of the VARCHAR fields to less than 768 bytes, or index about the two `id` fields instead.

```
ALTER TABLE property_value
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_property_key_id FOREIGN KEY (property_key_id)
    REFERENCES property_key(id);
```